# Why can't I use Android Studio to view the source code of third-party libraries and can only see decompiled code?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: third lib]
[image: right top btn to download]
to download sources also failed,Could not GET 'https://www.jitpack.io/com/github/CymChad/BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper/3.0.4@aar/BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper-3.0.4@aar.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request

so many

```
/* compiled code */
```

setting proxy didn't work........................................................................................

Comment: Providing source code packages is the responsibility of the used Maven repository. Seems like jitpack.io does not support providing source code packages.